# How to add CalDAV and CardDAV resources to Kontact?

Tags: kde, calendar, akonadi, korganizer, kontact

I just switched to **KDE** on my Ubuntu laptop, and am trying to use **Kontact** for a better desktop integration (I was previously using Evloution).

My problem is that I can't manage to ***add CardDAV nor CalDAV servers*** to my contacts and calendars...

My DAV server is **Sogo** (hosted by Gandi). The server works fine from Evolution and Android DAVx5 and syncs both ways from multiple devices.

What I do is (rough english translations as my system is in french):

1. `'add a contact book'` (or add a calendar in Korganizer)
2. then I choose `'Resource for GroupDAV'`
3. I'm presented with an assistant for `akonadi_davgroupware`, and asked for my credentials
4. then I can choose between different server types, but none of them is Sogo, so I choose `'Configure manually'`
5. then I can add a new server URL, which I do, choosing the right protocol (CardDAV)
6. OK button is greyed out, but I have an `'Extract'` button
7. I click on it and :
8. I get a warning that the server does not require authentication (?), and I accept to go further
9. and then... *nothing*

Same scenario happens with CalDAV.

So... how can I troubleshoot this ? Where am'I wrong ??

EDIT1: just realised that there is a Sogo entry in the serveur types list, under "Scalable OGo". Trying that, I get the same error message about the server not requiering authentication, and no calendar / address book is created...